# Python not extracting words correctly

Tags: python

I've been trying to get my code to extract the last word in an unsorted list (the list is sorted in the code) pyramid type structure for the past several hours and just can't seem to get it. The pyramid functions, but my code keeps giving me the first word in each row instead of the last.

As an example the list could be:

```
3 select
2 paragraph
5 always
6 poem
1 chick
4 planet
```

This list is sorted into the correct order by number in the code. after being sorted its put into a pyramid structure like such.

1
2 3
4 5 6

The output I get is `chick paragraph planet`, but should be `chick select poem` the list data is being grabbed from this file text_`file.txt`.

This is what I have tried, but I'm really stumped as to why it keep grabbing the first word in each row over the last word as I expected.

```
def unscramble_lines_from_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = [line.strip() for line in file]
        sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))
        return sorted_lines
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "File not found."
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid input. Please ensure each line starts with a valid number."

def create_pyramid_from_unscrambled_lines(lines):
    try:
        numbers = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]

        pyramid = []
        current_number = 1
        max_number = max(numbers)
        for level in range(1, max_number + 1):
            row = [line.split()[1] for line in lines if int(line.split()[0]) == current_number]
            pyramid.append(row)
            current_number += level

        # Print the sorted list
        print("Sorted List:")
        for line in lines:
            print(line)


        last_words = [row[-1].split()[-1] if row else '' for row in pyramid]  # Extract last word from each row

        return ' '.join(last_words)
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid input. Please ensure each line starts with a valid number."

# Example usage:
input_file_path = "text_file.txt"
unscrambled_result = unscramble_lines_from_file(input_file_path)

last_words_result = create_pyramid_from_unscrambled_lines(unscrambled_result)

print("\nLast Words from Each Row:")
print(last_words_result)
```

Comment: The list `row` can contain at most one item at each time because of the requirement `if int(line.split()[0]) == current_number` in the list comprehension (and because each line has a different number).

Comment: so your expecting `chick select poem` as the output?

Comment: yes im expecting `chick select poem` (these values are just an example)

Comment: [Edit] the question to show the properly formatted input file, the desired output of your code, and the actual output of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
def gen_sorted(text):
    x = text.split(' ')
    d = dict(zip(x[0::2], x[1::2]))
    return [d.get(k) for k in sorted(d.keys())]

def get_triangular(n):
    return sum(range(n+1))

def get_edge(sorted_word_list):
    n = 1
    i = get_triangular(n)
    words = []
    while i<=len(sorted_word_list):
        words.append(sorted_word_list[i-1])
        n+=1
        i = get_triangular(n)
    return " ".join(words)
        
sorted_word_list = gen_sorted("3 select 2 paragraph 5 always 6 poem 1 chick 4 planet")
get_edge(sorted_word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out. the issue was within `current_number`

```
def unscramble_lines_from_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = [line.strip() for line in file]
        sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))
        return sorted_lines
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "File not found."
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid input. Please ensure each line starts with a valid number."

def create_pyramid_from_unscrambled_lines(lines):
    try:
        # Extract the numbers and sort the lines by these numbers
        numbers = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
        sorted_lines = sorted(zip(numbers, lines), key=lambda x: x[0])

        pyramid = []
        current_level = 1
        while sorted_lines:
            # Take the first 'current_level' items from the sorted list for the current level of the pyramid
            level_lines = [sorted_lines.pop(0)[1] for _ in range(current_level) if sorted_lines]
            # Join the lines to form one string for the current level
            pyramid.append(' '.join(level_lines))
            current_level += 1  # Increment the level

        # Print the sorted list
        print("Sorted List:")
        for line in lines:
            print(line)

        # Extract the last word from each row of the pyramid
        last_words = [row.split()[-1] for row in pyramid if row]

        return ' '.join(last_words)
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid input. Please ensure each line starts with a valid number."

# Example usage:
input_file_path = "text_file.txt"
unscrambled_result = unscramble_lines_from_file(input_file_path)

last_words_result = create_pyramid_from_unscrambled_lines(unscrambled_result)

print("\nLast Words from Each Row:")
print(last_words_result)
```